# Building docker image, inside an alpine linux container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

We are using docker containers running alpine linux as build agents in bamboo. As part of the build plan a docker image needs to be created.

Our build agent has docker installed, however we are getting errors as the docker daemon isn't running. Starting the daemon with

```
/usr/local/bin/dockerd
```

gives the following:

```
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 640 
ERRO[0001] 'overlay' is not supported over overlayfs    
INFO[0001] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds 
INFO[0001] Loading containers: start.                   
WARN[0001] Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
, error: exit status 1 
WARN[0001] Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message: `modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory`, error: exit status 1 
WARN[0001] Running modprobe xt_conntrack failed with message: `modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory`, error: exit status 1 
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain: Iptables not found
```

To try and get round this I've installed iptables. Now when I try to run the docker daemon I get:

```
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 705 
ERRO[0001] 'overlay' is not supported over overlayfs    
INFO[0001] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds 
INFO[0001] Loading containers: start.                   
WARN[0001] Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
, error: exit status 1 
WARN[0001] Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message: `modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory`, error: exit status 1 
WARN[0001] Running modprobe xt_conntrack failed with message: `modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory`, error: exit status 1 
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

I'm a little stuck on where to go now as sudo isn't a thing on alpine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the Docker daemon inside the Docker container is generally a dodgy prospect.  We have this exact same requirement, and we solve it by mounting `/var/run/docker.sock` from the Docker host into the Docker container:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged
```

That way the `docker` command inside the build agent container is actually talking to the Docker daemon on the host, not inside the container.  Works really well for us.

Comment: thanks, gone with this option. Although I didn't have to run with --privileged

Comment: Here's an article that describes the pro's and con's of running docker-in-docker. It also gives some insights into the solution described above: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/